# Printer code doesn't find printers under Windows but works under OS X

Tags: java, printing

Under Mac OS X (Lion), this print method works okay. Under Windows, it does nothing; it doesn't find any printers, and the menu list remains blank.

I use this class for sending my page:

```
new SelectPrinterDialog(this, new PrintContent(this, ord_id, this.sessionID));
```

In the class `PrintContent`, I use:

```
private DocFlavor flavor;
```

and

```
PrintService[] getPrinters(){
```

to find printers.

```
public class PrintContent {

    private static final boolean TEXT = false;

    private OrdiniFrame frame;
    private String content;
    private long ordID;
    private long sessionID;
    private DocFlavor flavor;

public static final String PDF_PRINT_FILE = "__temp_print_file.pdf";
public static final String TXT_PRINT_FILE = "__temp_print_file.txt";
public static final String HTML_PRINT_FILE = "__temp_print_file.html";

public PrintContent(OrdiniFrame frame, long ordID, long sessionID){
    this.frame = frame;
    this.ordID = ordID;
    this.sessionID = sessionID;
    if(TEXT){
        this.flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_US_ASCII;
        this.generateText();
    }
    else {
        this.flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT;
        this.generateHTML();
    }

}


public PrintService[] getPrinters(){
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    //aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A8);
    return PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);
}

public XHTMLPrintable createRender () {
    try{
        XHTMLPanel renderer = new XHTMLPanel();
        renderer.getSharedContext().setDPI(300f);
        renderer.setDocument(new File(HTML_PRINT_FILE));
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(renderer, "Center");
        f.setVisible(true);
        return new XHTMLPrintable(renderer);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public void print(PrintService service){

    try{
        float paperWidth = 62.0f;
        // paperHeight aumenta l'altezza del foglio
        float paperHeight = 70.0f;
        paperWidth *= 2.83;
        paperHeight *= 2.83;

        //val printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        printJob.setPrintService(service);

        PageFormat pageFormat = printJob.defaultPage();
        pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
        Paper labelPaper = pageFormat.getPaper();
        labelPaper.setSize(paperWidth, paperHeight);
        labelPaper.setImageableArea(+30,+30,paperWidth, paperHeight);
        pageFormat.setPaper(labelPaper);

        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(this.createRender(), pageFormat);
        printJob.setPageable(book);

        PrintRequestAttributeSet attributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attributeSet.add(new PrinterResolution(300, 300, ResolutionSyntax.DPI));
        printJob.print(attributeSet);

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE:
I've solved.
The problem was in the tag html-> `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`!!!
I found this error after creating a file .bat for the execution of .jar.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you should either post your answer below, which you can accept after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely. You should *not* simply edit your question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved. The problem was in the tag html-> !!! I found this error after creating a file .bat for the execution of .jar.